# trying to increment an ID from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Rails so I'm sorry if I need to be more clear with anything.  I'm trying to create a survey app, where an admin adds a different amount of questions to a survey and then a user answers them.  The problem I'm running into is when a user answers a question I want them to be taken to the next question, which in this case would be the next question in the index.  This is what the create path looks like in my answers controller

```
def create
question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
@answer = question.answers.new(answer_params)
if @answer.save
  flash[:notice] = 'answer saved'
  render :'question/(question.id + 1)/answers/new'
else
  @question = Question.find(@answer.question_id)
  @answers = @question.answers
  flash[:notice] = @answer.errors.full_messages.join(". ")

  render :'question/(:question_id + 1)/answers/new'
end
end
```

I'm not married to this probably inelegant solution and am open to any ideas as to how to accomplish it.  Thanks

Comment: `Question.find(params[:question_id].to_i + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have set up you routes the rails way with `resources`

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers 
end
```

This gives you a helper method named `new_question_answer_path` which can be used for the redirect.

```
def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answer =  @question.answers.new(answer_params)
  if @answer.save
    if nq = Question.find_by(id: @question.id + 1)
      redirect_to new_question_answer_path(question_id: nq)
    else
      # do something else
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you are using render where you should be redirecting - and passing a url to render in the else clause. You might want to read up on the difference.